# calling a method in a model from another controller in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application I need to call a method defined in one table  from another controller. There are two tables named coordinates and tweets. The condition for the tweets table is decided by the coordinates table. In my final view I need to  display the attributes of the tweets table for which the condition is decided by the  coordinates table.
My Coordinates table code

```
  class Coordinates<ActiveRecord::Base
      def self.query()
        a = Coordinates.where("city=?", params[:show])
        b = a.first
        if a.count == 1
          latitude = b.latitude
          longitude= b.longitude
          if(latitude=0 && longitude=0) then
            return  sql="Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%text%' AND user_loc LIKE '%show%' order by id desc"
          else if (latitude!=0 && longitude!=0) 
                 min_lat = latitude - 1.0
                 max_lat = latitude + 1.0
                 min_lng = longitude - 1.0
                 max_lng = longitude + 1.0
                 return   sql = "Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%text%' AND ( ((longitude BETWEEN min_lng and max_lng) AND (latitude BETWEEN min_lat and max_lat)) OR (user_loc LIKE '%show%') ) order by id desc"
               else
                 return   sql="Select * from  tweets where tweet_text LIKE  '%text%'"
               end    
          end
        end
```

My tweets table

```
class Tweets<ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :id, :tweet_created_at, :tweet_id, :tweet_text, :tweet_source, :user_id, :user_name, :user_sc_name, :user_loc, :user_img, :longitude, :latitude, :place, :country

end
```

I need to call the query definition from my tweets_controller  so that it decides what query to fetch from the tweets table and display in the final view . But  the params function is not working in the model.rb file . I want something like this
My tweets_controller.rb

```
class TweetsController<ApplicationController
  def index
    Coordinates.query()
  end
end
```

My final view code

```
<%= @tweets.each do |tweets| %>

<ul>

  <li><%= tweets.id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_created_at %></li>

  <li><%= tweets.tweet_source %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_text %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_name %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_sc_name %></li>
<li><%= tweets.user_loc %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_img %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.longitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.latitude %></li>
<li><%= tweets.place %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.country %></li>

</ul>
<% end %>
```

I am not able to call the query function defined in  coordinates table from tweetscontroller. Also  I tried using helper methods but that does not seem to help and sounds very complicated. Anybody kindly help me with this

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I see a few issues with your code.

First off: use meaningful names. You are retrieving tweets pertaining to a certain city. Secondly, in your `query` method, most of what you are trying to do is retrieving tweets, which should be in the tweet model.

What your code does wrong:

- it just builds the sql?
- it searches for tweets containing the fixed text `%text%`, I am assuming that should be a given search-term
- it searches for a given user-location `%show%`, I am assuming that should be the city-name (your `params[:show]`

What I would suggest:

- finding tweets should be in `Tweet` model
- use more smaller methods
- for simplicity I assume your search-term is `params[:text]`

So I would write your code as follows:

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    city = params[:show]
    search_term = params[:text]
    city_coordinates = Coordinates.where('city=?', city)
    @tweets = if city_coordinates.count == 1 && city_coordinates.first.valid_location?
                Tweet.for_coordinate(city_coordinates.first)
              else
                Tweet.for_user_location(city)
              end
    @tweets = @tweets.where("tweet_text like ?", "%#{search_term}%")
  end
end
```

Do not build the sql yourself, let activerecord do that for you. Also: `where` is lazy, so you can easily chain them.

Then in your `Coordinate` model add

```
class Coordinate < ActiveRecord::Base

  def valid_location?
    self.latitude != 0 && self.longitude != 0
  end

end
```

and in your `Tweet` model

```
class Tweet  < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.for_coordinate(coordinate)
    bbox = { min_lat: coordinate.latitude - 1.0, max_lat: coordinate.latitude + 1.0,
             min_lng: coordinate.latitude - 1.0, max_lng: coordinate.latitude + 1.0
           }
    Tweet.where("(longitude BETWEEN ? and ?) AND (latitude BETWEEN ? and ?)) OR (user_loc LIKE ?)", 
       bbox[:min_lng], bbox[:max_lng], bbox[:min_lat], bbox[:max_lat], "%#{coordinate.city}%")

  end

  def self.for_user_location(city)
    Tweet.where("user_loc like ?", "%#{city}%")  
  end

end
```

Comment: thks a ton. It helped me a lot and bought me  very close. Its routing to the proper controller since its showing the latitude of that place but it says "undefined method '-' in app/models/tweets.rb. In this line    "bbox = { min_lat: coordinates.latitude - 1.0, max_lat: coordinates.latitude + 1.0,". Can you help me ? minus symbol

Comment: Are you using ruby 1.9.3?

Comment: ya I am using ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Well, you are probably not showing me the complete error. It should be something like `undefined method '-' for ...`. So somehow `coordinates.latitude` is not an integer I guess. In my example I called it `coordinate`, not plural (since it is only one coordinate).

Comment: but i have named the model as Coordinates only . is there any rule that I should declare objects using singular only?

Comment: Wel most of the times a model is singular, because it is in a table/controller handling the multiple, but a location has two coordinates, so I get that. So I would rather have `Position` or `Location` as the model-name. More importantly: did you find the bug? Show the complete error if not please.

Comment: it says undefined symbol '-' for 'some no' in app/models/tweets.rb .where  'some no' is the latitude for eg 74.25,18.95 etc .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35212/discussion-between-user2492854-and-nathanvda)

Answer (score 2):

In your `self.query` method in model, set an argument like this :

```
class Coordinates<ActiveRecord::Base

      def self.query(something)
        a = Coordinates.where("city=?", something)
        b = a.first
        if a.count == 1
          latitude = b.latitude
          longitude= b.longitude
          if(latitude=0 && longitude=0) then
            return  sql="Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%text%' AND user_loc LIKE '%show%' order by id desc"
          else if (latitude!=0 && longitude!=0) 
                 min_lat = latitude - 1.0
                 max_lat = latitude + 1.0
                 min_lng = longitude - 1.0
                 max_lng = longitude + 1.0
                 return   sql = "Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%text%' AND ( ((longitude BETWEEN min_lng and max_lng) AND (latitude BETWEEN min_lat and max_lat)) OR (user_loc LIKE '%show%') ) order by id desc"
               else
                 return   sql="Select * from  tweets where tweet_text LIKE  '%text%'"
               end    
          end
        end
```

In your controller, pass your `params[:show]` as as parameter :

```
class TweetsController<ApplicationController
 def index
  @tweets = Coordinates.query(params[:show])
 end
end
```

Now it should work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You call `Coordinates.query()` but you don't actually store the return value.

Try this:

`@tweets = Coordinates.query()`

Comment: It says undefined method 'params' in Coordinates model. How should I proceed?